# 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSession'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am building an app using ASP.NET Core 2.0 which was earlier using Core 1.0. After migration everything seems to be working fine but when i try to use Session method `app.UseSession()` then it throws following error:

> 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSession' and no extension method 'UseSession' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried installing `ASPNETCore.Session` package from NuGet but couldn't.

Can anyone help me finding the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/) Nuget package?

Comment: I tried installing the refence from nuGet but it's rolling back. Won't let me install it

Comment: Then you need to solve that problem first.

Comment: @DavidG That's what i am not able to point out. It was showing another error in the errorList but it's due to tsconfig.json file , saying "The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the following project(S)". I saw a similar issue here itself and it just gave me more error while attaching the same to the root of the project. "Source input of tsconfig.json couldn't be found"

Comment: That's just more problems with your project that need fixing. Sort them out before asking why you can't add sessions to your project.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't update some of your dependencies too the correct versions. Want to share your dependencies list?

Answer (score 0):

First inject Session Service into your `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
      // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
      options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2400);
      options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});
```

then use `app.UseSession();` in `Configure` Method.

In ASP.NET Core Session doesn't support Generic data type you'll need to add this extension

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session,string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

and to use it:

```
public IActionResult SetDate()
{
    // Requires you add the Set extension method mentioned in the article.
    HttpContext.Session.Set<DateTime>(SessionKeyDate, DateTime.Now);
    return RedirectToAction("GetDate");
}

public IActionResult GetDate()
{
    // Requires you add the Get extension method mentioned in the article.
    var date = HttpContext.Session.Get<DateTime>(SessionKeyDate);
    var sessionTime = date.TimeOfDay.ToString();
    var currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();

    return Content($"Current time: {currentTime} - "
                 + $"session time: {sessionTime}");
}
```